# how to resolve this sonarQube bug about hashmap in java

Tags: java, hashmap, sonarqube

I have a hashMap :
`private static Map<String, JSONObject> laserDataList = new HashMap<String, JSONObject>();`
I wrote this part of code :

`public void execute(JSONObject object) {JSONObject reportData = laserDataList.get(JSONUtil.getAsJSONObject(object, LoanOntologyKeys.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID)); }`
Sonar says this code has problem  : **A "Map<String, JSONObject>" cannot contain a "JSONObject" in a "String" type**

how can I resolve this bug ? what is the meaning of this sonar message ?

Comment: Please share which Json library you are using.

Comment: Don't you see you're calling `get()` with something that is not a string?

Comment: what should I use instead of get () ? @Olivier

Comment: JSONObject reportData = laserDataList.get(
                                JSONUtil.getAsJSONObject(object, LoanOntologyKeys.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID) != null
                                ? JSONUtil.getAsJSONObject(object, LoanOntologyKeys.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID).toString() : null);  Is this a good solution for this problem ? @Olivier

Answer (score 0):

I can see from the comments that you're not understanding the problem.

You've defined a Map object.  You've specified that the keys of the map are of type String, and the values are of type JSONObject.

When you look up a value in a map, you pass to the "get" method a value of the KEY type, and you get back a value of the VALUE type.  In this case, again, the key type is String, and the value type is JSONObject.  Your calls to "JSONUtil.getAsJSONObject()" all return JSONObject values, not strings.

I don't know exactly what your logic is doing, but perhaps you need this:

```
JSONObject reportData = laserDataList.get(LoanOntologyKeys.PRINT_DOCUMENT_ID);
```